# Replying to a digitally signed email using thunderbird

Tags: certificates, smime

So Basically I sent a digitally signed email using a certificate issued by Sectigo RSA Client Authentication and Secure Email CA.

Now the recipient of the email replied to me with a certificate issued by COMODO RSA Client Authentication and Secure Email CA. It also said that the Digital Signature is not valid.

I tried replying with an encrypted message and digitally signed but it gives me an error:

So what I have done is exported the .crt file of the senders certificate and I added it into the "People's Certificate" Tab in the "Manage Certificate" settings but still it won't send the email

```
Sending of the message failed.
You specified encryption for this message, but the application failed to      
find an encryption certificate for johndoe@gmail.com
```

Comment: Doessn't Thunderbird give you any more details about why the signature is considered invalid?

Comment: I think COMODO S/MIME certs may not be trusted anymore. Look at **why** the signature is untrusted, and also at whether the certificate is trusted (both valid and has a valid chain of trust to a trusted root authority) or not. If it isn't valid, Thunderbird will certainly not use it. If it doesn't chain to a trusted root, you will have to manually mark it as trusted (or import ant trust its root) if you consider it legit.